# Rotation Automation

Tags: expression, maya

I've run into a few problems with this expression in Maya, basically anytime the radius is less than 1, the calculation is thrown off way too much.

```
float $radius = `getAttr prefix66_calculations_shape.rad`;
float $prevZval = `getAttr -time (frame -1) prefix66_driver.translateZ`;
float $prevXval = `getAttr -time (frame -1) prefix66_driver.translateX`;
float $Zval = prefix66_driver.translateZ - $prevZval;
float $Xval = prefix66_driver.translateX - $prevXval;
float $distance = ($Zval * $Zval) + ($Xval * $Xval);
float $direction;
$distance = sqrt($distance);
if ($prevZval > prefix66_driver.translateZ) {
    $direction = 360;
}
else { 
    $direction = 360;
}
float $rotation = ($distance / (2 * 3.142 * $radius)) * $direction;
print $rotation;
pCube1.rotateX = pCube1.rotateX + $rotation;
```

Maybe my order of operations is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If its a wheel of a car you need to account for the angke of your wheel toward line of movement. anyway do **NOT** use **`getAttr -time (frame -1) prefix66_driver.translateZ`** cache the alue form last frame.

Comment: I did read your last post, I did spend about 3 hours with the framecache node, although it didn't update dynamically, as in if I was to connect the translate Z into the stream, what ever the value was when it was connected, it doesn't update with time.

I don't understand how using node.cacheTx = objname.tx; node.tx = node.cacheTx; would work though, wouldn't they equal the exact same values?

Comment: PS: I'm trying to automate the rolling speed of a wheel moved in local direction, this does work almost seamlessly, only problem is smaller objects with a radius less than 1 seem to evaluate wrong.

Comment: Well it becomes than a simulation with all problems associated with this. But I to recall this has been already done you can download the expression form highend3d for example. There is some convolution in this if you need to account for moving upwards on slopes and need to reverse. This uninteresting solution, as it makes animating a pain. PS: on frame cache yes that's the idea it caches the values, if you want to redo them you need to disconnect and reconnect the node. But your gettAttr is really disastrous for mayas use as its now connected to a name, and breaks the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out :)

Queering the old traslation average, with the new translation average will give me a true or false answer, which is what I needed to change direction.

Also added an if statement that if the ball is static and rotating, that the wheel doesn't turn automatically.

```
float $oldRotateAverage;
float $oldTransAverage;
float $direction;

nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateX = nurbsCircle1.translateX - nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateX;
nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateY = nurbsCircle1.translateY - nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateY;
nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateZ = nurbsCircle1.translateZ - nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateZ;
nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateX = nurbsCircle1.translateX;
nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateY = nurbsCircle1.translateY;
nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateZ = nurbsCircle1.translateZ;
nurbsCircle1.Distance = mag(<<nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateX,nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateY,nurbsCircle1.DeltaTranslateZ>>);

if ($oldTransAverage >= (nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateX + nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateY + nurbsCircle1.LastTranslateZ)){
    $direction = -360.00;
} else {
    $direction = 360.00;
};

if (Sh54_anim.auto == 1 )
{
    Sh54_point_grp.rotateZ -= nurbsCircle1.Distance * $direction / 2 / 3.14 / 2;    
};

if ((nurbsCircle1.rotateX + nurbsCircle1.rotateY + nurbsCircle1.rotateZ) != $oldRotateAverage && nurbsCircle1.Distance == $oldTransAverage){
    Sh54_anim.auto = 0;
} else {
    Sh54_anim.auto = 1;
};

Sh54_point_grp.back_up = Sh54_point_grp.translateX;
$oldRotateAverage = nurbsCircle1.rotateX + nurbsCircle1.rotateY + nurbsCircle1.rotateZ;
$oldTransAverage = nurbsCircle1.translateX + nurbsCircle1.translateY + nurbsCircle1.translateZ;
```

Comment: glad to see you solved it. Sorry I couldn't spare time lately. Its a great learning exercise to get machine parts working in relation to each other with expressions in Maya, however once you get simple stuff going, you soon want steering, skidding, suspension etc. You soon find yourself mimicking  everything that goes on in a physics simulation. You'll be surprised how easy it is to set up a rigid body system to get the same effect. I saw someone make a convincing tank with dynamica recently. It was driving over uneven terrain and the treads were rattling about very realistically.

Comment: Very interesting, the only thing I haven't achieved is scaling the rig and still keeping propper speed/animation.

Comment: @JulianMann don't go down voting just because I was reviewing my account. I was told to do this by S.O, I have changed my answers because my answers are the correct one, you may have helped me, however the correct answer is in my script not yours.

Answer (score 1):

The rotation part of your code looks ok. However, you have an if/else block that returns the same thing in both cases, and as mentioned by @joojaa, you can avoid `getAttr -time` if you cache the translation values. In fact you should avoid `getAttr` and `setAttr` completely in expressions.

Instead, refer to the attributes you want directly and Maya will create connections for you. This is much faster and less prone to errors when you rename nodes and so on.

To cache the translation values, and calculate change in position you can add attributes to the node and use them in the expression.

Let's say you have a cylinder called wheel that rotates around its local X and is parented to a group node called control:

Add a vector attribute: `control.lastTranslate`
Add a vector attribute: `control.deltaTranslate`
Add a float attribute: `control.distance`

Here's an expression that will store the change in translation, then rotate the wheel based on the distance travelled.

```
// When deltaTranslate is calculated, lastTranslate still has its previous value.
control.deltaTranslateX = control.translateX - control.lastTranslateX;
control.deltaTranslateY = control.translateY - control.lastTranslateY;
control.deltaTranslateZ = control.translateZ - control.lastTranslateZ;
control.lastTranslateX = control.translateX;
control.lastTranslateY = control.translateY;
control.lastTranslateZ = control.translateZ;
control.distance = mag(<<control.deltaTranslateX,control.deltaTranslateY,control.deltaTranslateZ>>);

// Get radius from history node (or somewhere) and move the wheel's hub off the floor.
wheel.translateY = polyCylinder1.radius;

// add rotation to the wheel 
float $tau = 6.283185307179586;
wheel.rotateX = wheel.rotateX + ( control.distance* -360.0) /  (polyCylinder1.radius * $tau );
```

It's best to test this kind of thing by animating rather than dragging nodes around in the view.

If you wanted to make the wheel aim to the direction of travel, you could add a locator at translate + deltaTranslate and hook up an aim constraint.

e.g.

```
aimLocator.translateX = (control.deltaTranslateX / control.distance) + control.translateX;
aimLocator.translateY = (control.deltaTranslateY / control.distance) + control.translateY;
aimLocator.translateZ = (control.deltaTranslateZ / control.distance) + control.translateZ;
```

Dividing by distance will normalize the offset. You should probably check that distance is not zero.

Comment: This seems quite promising @julian! I've had a bit of a play with it, but how can I "switch" or calculate the direction with flipping the wheel so to speak with an aim constraint. I don't fully understand, but what I have seems to work quite nicely thanks to you!

Comment: I see what you mean. The expression above only knows how far you went, and not whether you are going forward or back. There are a couple of options. To automatically shift from forward to reverse, you can compare the direction you are facing to the direction you are moving. This implies that you manually control the direction you are facing. Alternatively you can set the orientation automatically to the direction you are moving. In this case the wheels are always rolling forward and you have no manual control. I'll edit my answer with details of each as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Thankyou heaps! That would be great!

Comment: Have you had a chance yet Julian?

Comment: Ah - sorry - I haven't had a chance. I'm under crazy deadline  pressure at the moment so I will not be able to focus until Wednesday. I hope that's not too late. You can send me a reminder at julian dot mann at gmail dot com and I'll be happy to set it up.

Comment: Hi Julian, Not sure if you've been receiving my emails, but I'm wondering if you've had the time to look at this yet?